# Method tableView.reloadData() not working

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to develop an iOS app.my story is I have the completion for handle new data from API that notify by socket IO, every time socket on success I want to reload tableview.and the socket work fine. The problem is When I First Login my app for the first time the method tableview.reload not work but when I rerun my project everything is fine.so I want to ask why tableview does not reload for the first time right here?.
Thank you in advance!!

*Note1: for tableview.reloadData() not working I mean it doesn't call calls cellForRowAtIndexPath I've already printed and set a breakpoint on the method cellForRowAtIndexPath*

*Note2: tableview render tableViewCell once and I try to call tableview.reloadData() to render cell again to update UI but it doesn't work.*

This is my code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad() 
   ....................
   ChatSocketManagerOnline.shared.lastMessageOn { (data) in
   self.data = data            
   self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

Comment: Have you set the dataSource of the tableView?

Comment: What do you mean it does not work? What happens?

Comment: Based on your question, the problem you face is understandable but we need more info to filter why/how/where it happens. Have you tried using any `print` statements or breakpoints to see if you receive any data for the first time? Would be better if you can include what you've tried as a part of the question too

Comment: try it on main thread ...

Comment: @PGDev yes I have

Comment: @andlin I mean it does not update interface to display

Comment: Make sure that your `tableView` is visible. (perhaps adding something static to your `data`) If it is not or the width and maybe height is zero then `cellForRow(at:)` function will never get called.

Answer (score 0):

```
try

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad() 
   ....................
   ChatSocketManagerOnline.shared.lastMessageOn { [weak self] (data) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.data = data            
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you put `ChatSocketManagerOnline.shared.lastMessageOn` in `viewDidLoad()` so your Table View will be reloaded data once when you run app.
Please read document https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload

You should use a NotificationCenter to detect when socket success then reload tableview.

Comment: As you said  reload data shouldn't run at any time but for in my case when I rerun the application for the second time it's work. as a result like that, I don't know what I miss right here. anyway, thank you for your help.